# Applying Alpha page transformer to ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, transform

I am implementing ViewPager Transformer where, Text Alpha should slowly transformed from 0.3f(Unselected Page) - 1.0f(Selected Page) as we are swiping in viewpager.

Here is the Desired output. [Viewpager Transformation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vPTt.png)

As I am new to Android, I tried following approach, basically I am confused in what formula to apply.

```
public class AlphaTextTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

 public void transformPage(@NonNull View view, float position) {
  int pageWidth = view.getWidth();
  if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
   // This page is way off-screen to the left.
   view.setAlpha(0.3 f);

  } else if (position <= 0) { // [-1,0]
   // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page
   view.setAlpha(0.3 f);

  } else if (position <= 1) { // (0,1]
   // Fade the page out.
   view.setAlpha(0.3 f + Math.abs(position));

  } else { // (1,+Infinity]
   // This page is way off-screen to the right.
   view.setAlpha(0.3 f);
  }
 }
}
```

I show 3 pages in screen at a time.Left & Right page are partially shown with Text alpha value to 0.3f.Center page text has alpha value of 1. I don't want to immediately set alpha value to 1, but rather it will be progressive as we perform sliding. Can someone please help me with correct pointer? I would really appreciate if someone can help me with Sample code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the value of postion with breakpoint or log? Maybe it does not correspond to your expected value?

You should check on [this library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6324)'s code to see how it works, it's with pagetransformer